# react-native-auth0 two authdomains for test/prod

Tags: react-native, react-native-auth0

Why do we need to provide the auth0Domain in buildgradle with react-native-auth0?

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Add the next line
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN", auth0Scheme: "${applicationId}.auth0"]
    }
    ...
}
```

When we use the Auth0Provider we provide it with domain and clientId.

```
 <Auth0Provider domain={AUTH0_DOMAIN} clientId={AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}>
        ....rest
 </Auth0Provider>
```

So I do not understand, why is this needed? I'm currently having some issues with having multiple auth domains depending on if you're in test/prod.

I've tried doing:

```
def ENV = System.getenv()
def AUTH0_DOMAIN = ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN']

manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN, auth0Scheme: "${applicationId}"]
```

But this does not work. Not sure if it fails to read the AUTH0_DOMAIN variable.

I still don't see why I need this though.
When logging in I provide my own redirectURL:

```
  const result = await authorize({
      audience: 'audience',
      redirectUrl: URLfromENV,
    })
```

However, this only works if I actually hardcode the auth0Domain in the manifestPlaceholder.
Any tips on this matter is highly appreciated.